# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'serial'

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port

This is Arduino Python.

The Python script is giving me an error with the following line:

`import serial`

The error is:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'serial'`

I want to understand the relationship between the software libraries.  where is the serial library? 
I think the library is there, but the present Python script is not finding it.
john

Comment: You _think the library is there_ ? Did you install it?

Answer (score 4):

After checking to see if it is there like @araldo-van-de-kraats says (`pip freeze`), it looks like you probably want to make sure you've installed pySerial:

```
pip install pyserial
```

See the documentation [here](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial.html#installation).

Answer (score 1):

From the command line, check if it is installed with:

```
pip freeze
```

If it is not installed, you can install it with:

```
pip install serial
```